# Cannot use object of type MongoId as array when trying to extract Mongo ID hex code

Tags: php, mongodb, objectid

I'm trying to extract the hex code of a Mongo ID ObjectId using PHP. This error comes up whenever I try to extract the ID number and store it in another variable.

var_dumping the contents of a document fetched by a Mongo query gives something like the following:

```
object(MongoId)#242 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "52795dc1613f4547710000df" }
```

So to get that $id string, I do this:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@localhost/database");
$db = $mongo->selectDb("database");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("someCollection");
$doc = $collection->find( /* some query to get a document here */ )->getNext();

$recordId = $doc["_id"]['$id'];
```

And this gives the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type MongoId as array
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `var_dump()` of an MongoId is a bit missleading. The `$doc["_id"]` holds an *object* and not an *array* with a *string*, which you assume in your last line of code.

If you want the string representation of a MongoId just do this:

```
$recordId = (string) $doc["_id"];
```

or

```
$recordId = "{$doc['_id']}";
```